# Fading multiple divs on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I got a scrollable page containing a lot of `divs`. I want to `fade out` the elements at the `top` and `bottom` of the page while the user is scrolling; so only the divs which are currently in the center of the `viewport` will have an `opacity` of 100%.

[image: divs with opacity depending on their position]

I am currently achieving this by observing the `window.scroll` event and calculating each divs `opacity` by their position in relation to the `scroll offsets`. This works, but has an huge impact on the clients performance (specially when there are a lot of divs) - which leads to a "non fluid" scrolling experience.

Are there other approaches available? Maybe even a solution without going through every single div?

---

### Edit:

1. I setup a quick preview on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/eUGae/3/), which illustrates my current approach (not optimized)
2. Thanks for you comments! I really like the idea of using a `background gradient` to fake the elements opacity - but in my case this won't work, because I got an `background image`.

Comment: Your code would somewhat help

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a better approach. That sounds like exactly how I would do it too. I don't think the performance issues are with going through each div, but with the graphics chipset of the client struggling to constantly redraw the page.

Comment: One thing you could do is have a gradient background, and not change the transparency on the divs. That way as they scroll, the background makes them appear to disappear.

Comment: Make sure you only perform the calculations on the divs that are in the actual viewport of the browser.

Comment: thanks so far guys, I updated the question with an example

Answer (score 3):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6BvA/1/)

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/340760
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

// when you scroll the div
$(".list").scroll(function(e) {
    var $list = $(this);

    // apply logic only to visible elements
    $list.find("div")
        .filter(function(i, d) {
            return isScrolledIntoView(d);
        })
        .each(function() {
            var eTop = $(this).offset().top;
            var center = $list.height() / 2;

            // if the element is in the center it is 100%
            // otherwise it will fade
            var dif = center - eTop;
            if (dif < 0) dif *= -1;

            var pc = 1 - (dif / center);

            // set the opacity for the elements
            $(this).css("opacity", pc);
        });
});
```